# Ansible: Error executing shell script on target

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ansible

I've to run a shell script at the end of my playbook on RHEL 7 target servers.
I'm able to execute the script manually on target, but through ansible it errors out as below:

```
TASK [oracle_si_grid_install : executing the script to modify template values] **************************************************************************************************************
FAILED - RETRYING: executing the script to modify template values (3 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: executing the script to modify template values (2 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: executing the script to modify template values (1 retries left).
```

> fatal: [10.210.224.87]: FAILED! => {"attempts": 3, "changed": true, "cmd": "/tmp/modify_db_template.sh", "delta": "0:00:00.113423", "end": "2020-11-19 12:21:18.642239", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 2, "start": "2020-11-19 12:21:18.528816", "stderr": "/tmp/modify_db_template.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `<'\n/tmp/modify_db_template.sh: line 9:` while IFS= read -r line; do echo "processing line: $line"; sed -i "s|$line|         <initParam name=\"sga_target\" value=\"${SGA_TARGET}\" unit=\"MB\"/>|g" $DBCA_TEMPLATE; done < <(grep 'name="sga_target" value=' $DBCA_TEMPLATE)'", "stderr_lines": ["/tmp/modify_db_template.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `<'", "/tmp/modify_db_template.sh: line 9:` while IFS= read -r line; do echo "processing line: $line"; sed -i "s|$line|         <initParam name=\"sga_target\" value=\"${SGA_TARGET}\" unit=\"MB\"/>|g" $DBCA_TEMPLATE; done < <(grep 'name="sga_target" value=' $DBCA_TEMPLATE)'"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

**Ansible code for that module is as below:**

```yaml
- name: executing the script to modify template values
  shell: "/tmp/{{ modify_template }}"
  register: modtemp
  retries: 3
  delay: 2
  until: modtemp.rc == 0
  become: True
  become_user: "{{ db_user }}"
  become_method: su
```

Please note that I did use script / shell & added args: executable params too, but they fail as well.
The shell script is as follows:

```
if [ ! -e /tmp/benv.sh ]
then
  echo "No Env file found"
  exit -1
fi

source /tmp/benv.sh

while IFS= read -r line; do echo "processing line: $line"; sed -i "s|$line|         <initParam name=\"sga_target\" value=\"${SGA_TARGET}\" unit=\"MB\"/>|g" $DBCA_TEMPLATE; done < <(grep 'name="sga_target" value=' $DBCA_TEMPLATE)
while IFS= read -r line; do echo "processing line: $line"; sed -i "s|$line|         <initParam name=\"processes\" value=\"${DB_PROCESSES}\"/>|g" $DBCA_TEMPLATE; done < <(grep 'name="processes" value=' $DBCA_TEMPLATE)
while IFS= read -r line; do echo "processing line: $line"; sed -i "s|$line|         <initParam name=\"pga_aggregate_target\" value=\"${PGA_TARGET}\" unit=\"MB\"/>|g" $DBCA_TEMPLATE; done < <(grep 'name="pga_aggregate_target" value=' $DBCA_TEMPLATE)
#while IFS= read -r line; do echo "processing line: $line"; sed -i "s|$line|         <fileSize unit=\"KB\">${REDO_SIZE}</fileSize>|g" $DBCA_TEMPLATE; done < <(grep '<fileSize unit="KB">204800</fileSize>' $DBCA_TEMPLATE)
# if there are no disks for FRA, then recovery destination and related init params will be removed from template
while IFS= read -r line; do echo "processing line: $line"; [ -n "${ORA_LOG}" ] && sed -i "s|$line|         <initParam name=\"db_recovery_file_dest_size\" value=\"${RECOVERY_SIZE}\" unit=\"MB\"/>|g" $DBCA_TEMPLATE || sed -i "\|${line}|d" $DBCA_TEMPLATE; done < <(grep 'name="db_recovery_file_dest_size" value=' $DBCA_TEMPLATE )
while IFS= read -r line; do echo "processing line: $line"; [ -z "${ORA_LOG}" ] && sed -i "\|${line}|d" $DBCA_TEMPLATE; done < <(grep 'name="archive_lag_target" value=' $DBCA_TEMPLATE)
while IFS= read -r line; do echo "processing line: $line"; [ -z "${ORA_LOG}" ] && sed -i "\|${line}|d" $DBCA_TEMPLATE; done < <(grep 'name="control_file_record_keep_time" value=' $DBCA_TEMPLATE)
# if there is no BACKUP disk, then noarchivelog will be assumed
# if Oracle Cloud Backup module is used, then ORA_BACKUP must have a fake disk specified
while IFS= read -r line; do echo "processing line: $line"; [ -z "${ORA_LOG}" ] && sed -i "s|$line|         <archiveLogMode>false</archiveLogMode>|g" $DBCA_TEMPLATE ; done < <(grep '<archiveLogMode>true</archiveLogMode>' $DBCA_TEMPLATE)
```

Manually, it runs as expected

```
[oracle@ansible-poc6 ~]$ /tmp/modify_db_template.sh
processing line:          <initParam name="sga_target" value="9536" unit="MB"/>
processing line:          <initParam name="processes" value="1339"/>
processing line:          <initParam name="pga_aggregate_target" value="1906" unit="MB"/>
processing line:          <initParam name="db_recovery_file_dest_size" value="" unit="MB"/>
processing line:          <initParam name="archive_lag_target" value="900"/>
processing line:          <initParam name="control_file_record_keep_time" value="38"/>
processing line:          <archiveLogMode>true</archiveLogMode>
[oracle@ansible-poc6 ~]$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

Contents of /tmp/benv.sh

```
export DB_SID=oratest
export COMPLIANCE_TYPE="sox"
export CRITICALITY="critical"
export ORA_CHAR=AL32UTF8
export ORA_NCHAR=AL16UTF16
# storage vars - if more than one disk, then list separate with whitespace
export ORA_OCR="/dev/sdb"
export ORA_DATA="/dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf"
export ORA_SWAP=""
export ORA_LOG="/dev/sdg"
# constants
export BASE_ORA=/u01/app/oracle
export HOME_ORA=/u01/app/oracle/product/19/dbee_1
export HOME_CRS=/u01/app/19/grid
# template file
DBCA_TEMPLATE="/u01/app/oracle/product/19/dbee_1/assistants/dbca/templates/dbca-create-seeded.dbc"

# calculations
MEMORY=$(eval "echo $((`grep 'MemTotal:' /proc/meminfo | awk '{print $2}'` / 1024))") # [MB]
[ -n "${ORA_OCR}" ] && DB_MEMORY=$(eval "(( `echo $((MEMORY - 3072))` < `echo $((MEMORY * 8/10))` )) && echo $((MEMORY - 3072)) || echo $((MEMORY * 8/10))") || DB_MEMORY=$(eval "(( `echo $((MEMORY - 2048))` < `echo $((MEMORY * 8/10))` )) && echo $((MEMORY - 2048)) || echo $((MEMORY * 8/10))") # [MB]
DB_PROCESSES=$(eval "(( `echo $(( (DB_MEMORY+512) * 1000000 / 9868951 ))` < 320 )) && echo '320' || ((( `echo $(( (DB_MEMORY+512) * 1000000 / 9868951 ))` > 20000 )) && echo '20000' || echo $(( (DB_MEMORY+512) * 1000000 / 9868951 )))")
SGA_TARGET=$(eval "(( `echo $((DB_MEMORY * 75/100))` < 768 )) && echo '768' || echo $((DB_MEMORY * 75/100))") # [MB]
SGA_TARGET=$(eval "
if     [ ${SGA_TARGET} -le 1024 ]; then (( `echo $((SGA_TARGET%4))` > 0 )) && echo $((4-SGA_TARGET%4+SGA_TARGET)) || echo $SGA_TARGET;
elif   [ ${SGA_TARGET} -le 8192 ]; then (( `echo $((SGA_TARGET%16))` > 0 )) && echo $((16-SGA_TARGET%16+SGA_TARGET)) || echo $SGA_TARGET;
elif  [ ${SGA_TARGET} -le 16384 ]; then (( `echo $((SGA_TARGET%32))` > 0 )) && echo $((32-SGA_TARGET%32+SGA_TARGET)) || echo $SGA_TARGET;
elif  [ ${SGA_TARGET} -le 32768 ]; then (( `echo $((SGA_TARGET%64))` > 0 )) && echo $((64-SGA_TARGET%64+SGA_TARGET)) || echo $SGA_TARGET;
elif  [ ${SGA_TARGET} -le 65536 ]; then (( `echo $((SGA_TARGET%128))` > 0 )) && echo $((128-SGA_TARGET%128+SGA_TARGET)) || echo $SGA_TARGET;
elif [ ${SGA_TARGET} -le 131072 ]; then (( `echo $((SGA_TARGET%256))` > 0 )) && echo $((256-SGA_TARGET%256+SGA_TARGET)) || echo $SGA_TARGET;
else
(( `echo $((SGA_TARGET%512))` > 0 )) && echo $((512-SGA_TARGET%512+SGA_TARGET)) || echo $SGA_TARGET;
fi
") # [MB]
PGA_TARGET=$(eval "(( `echo $((DB_MEMORY * 15/100))` < 384 )) && echo '384' || echo $((DB_MEMORY * 15/100))") # [MB] pga over 20% will cause ORA-700
HUGEPAGES=$(eval "echo $((SGA_TARGET/2 + 1))")
SWAP_SIZE=$(eval "((`echo $((MEMORY - (HUGEPAGES * 2) + 4))` < 16384)) && echo $((MEMORY - (HUGEPAGES * 2) + 4)) || echo '16384'") # [MB]
```

Appreciate your time and help.
Thanks in advance

--
JK

Comment: Are you running the playbook as the same user as you do when you run the script manually?

Comment: Also, have you got a #! at the top of the script?

Comment: Yes, I'm running it as oracle user on target. Just added the #! but it still fails :(

Comment: What is the content of the sourced `/tmp/benv.sh` file ? Is your script relying on any vars set in your login environment on the target machine ? Ansible uses sh by default without any login initialization: did you try to set the [`executable` param](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#parameter-executable) to bash ?

Comment: You will need to add #!/bin/bash or #!/bin/st depending on the environment

Comment: @Zeitounator thanks for reply, I've updated the post with content of source /tmp/benv.sh file. Yes, the first one sets few params, which are using in /tmp/modify_db_template.sh.Also, I tried using executable param, but it still fails with same error.

Comment: @RamanSailopal, thanks, and I did the shebang. Still fails. Tried with output of which sh, which bash on target, but even after providing correct shebang, the script fails.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from module [shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html)

> "*... runs the command through a shell (/bin/sh) on the remote node.*"

You say *"Manually, it runs as expected"* in */bin/bash*. The error below is very probably caused by running the command in *bin/sh*.

```sh
"msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 2
"stderr": "/tmp/modify_db_template.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token <' ...
```

In Ansible, use parameter [executable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#parameter-executable) and run the command also in */bin/bash*. For example

```yaml
- name: executing the script to modify template values
  shell: "/tmp/{{ modify_template }}"
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  register: modtemp
  retries: 3
  delay: 2
  until: modtemp.rc == 0
  become: True
  become_user: "{{ db_user }}"
  become_method: su
```

Comment: I did that but still of no use:                                                                       ```- name: executing the script to modify template values
  raw: "/tmp/{{ modify_template }}"
  args:
    executable: /usr/bin/bash
  register: modtemp
  retries: 3
  delay: 2
  until: modtemp.rc == 0
  become: True
  become_user: "{{ db_user }}"
  become_method: su
```

Comment: Then find out what's the difference between running it manually and in Ansible.  Do not put the code into the comment. Update your question with the current code and current error message. Make it [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and isolate the problem to a couple of lines. Remove irrelevant pieces of the code 1) remove the test 2) keep single `while` line that causes the problem 3) reduce the complex sed arguments ... In other words, make it minimal, but complete and reproducible.